# Loop through table cells of a HTML table with a specific class name

Tags: vba, excel

I need to get the data in the cells of a `HTML table` whose class is `myClass` using Excel VBA.

This is my code:

```
Set HTMLDoc = oBrowser.document.getElementsByClassName("myClass")
For i = 0 To HTMLDoc.Length
   MsgBox HTMLDoc(i).innerHTML
Next i
```

Which is working OK while displaying the contents of the cells I'm looking for. But after running the loop I get the following error:

[image]

On line: `MsgBox HTMLDoc(i).innerHTML`

Comment: Do you know which statement the error the error is happening on?

Comment: Yes, sure! I forgot to mention: MsgBox HTMLDoc(i).innerHTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looping too many times.

The code needs to be:

```
For i = 0 To HTMLDoc.Length - 1
```

But some collections are 1 based in Excel VBA, meaning the call might need to be:

```
For i = 1 To HTMLDoc.Length
```

Comment: OK! The first option works. The second doesn't (it was also what I had initially thought) Thanks!

Comment: OK, so the collections are 0 based. :-)